# Cannot detect liquibase log file -Liquibase failed to start because no changelog could be found at 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml'

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a problem about detecting db.changelog-master.xml in Spring Boot app through Liquibase.

When I run the app, I get this issue shown below.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Liquibase failed to start because no changelog could be found at 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml'.

Action:

Make sure a Liquibase changelog is present at the configured path.
```

Here is my **application.yaml** file shown below.

```
liquibase:
  enabled: true
  change-log=classpath: /db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

Here is my **db.changelog-master.xml** shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <include file="/db/changelog/changes/a.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="/db/changelog/changes/b.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    ...

</databaseChangeLog>
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Where on the filesystem is your `db-changelog-master.xml` file and how are you running the application?

A [minimal, reproducible example](/help/mcve) would make this question much easier to answer.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson db-changelog-master.xml is under db/changelog

Comment: Does this answer your question? [changelog directory not found after spring boot 3 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75059387/changelog-directory-not-found-after-spring-boot-3-upgrade)

Comment: which version of liquibase and which version of spring-boot are you using? Maybe you should use `spring.liquibase.change-log`. In your yaml you are missing the `spring` prefix.